# Infinite-dimensional irreducible representations of countable abelian groups

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, infinite-groups, invariant-subspace

Doesn't seem exactly a research level question to me, so posting here instead of MO.

I seem to know a proof of the (counter-intuitive, in my opinion) fact that a countable abelian group may not have an infinite-dimensional irreducible complex representation. (Although I was very reluctant to believe it at first.)

1) Can someone knowledgeable confirm that this is indeed true?

2) How does this agree with [this](https://books.google.de/books?id=pO57CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=%22infinite-dimensional%20irreducible%20representations%20of%20z%22&source=bl&ots=DGGCwSNizK&sig=dQmVS-qMl_3H1zM5vSJ6FXPB3bA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH_K_nnZzQAhUGrRoKHcTRAhQQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22infinite-dimensional%20irreducible%20representations%20of%20z%22&f=false) passage (and, in general, the existence of counterexamples to the invariant subspace problem)? (I.e., is it true that some adjusted notion of a "representation" or "subrepresentation" is being used?)

**Update.** Since the link doesn't work for some people, [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9e1G.jpg) a screenshot from said book (Harmonic Analysis: Proceedings of the International Symposium, held at the Centre Universitaire of Luxembourg, September 7-11, 1987). Hope I'm within the law here =)

In particular, I'm referring to the paragraph starting with "on the other hand, ..."

Comment: Your "this" link leads to a page of the book that is not reachable.  Please quote or paraphrase it directly and state the name of the book.

Comment: @MarkFischler Thank you, I'm currently figuring out the best way to deal with this, will post an update shortly. (The link works by me though, I must say.)